# Regex find word contain specific char

Tags: python, regex

I want to find all the words that contains the char `'` one time.

for example:

```
'dog
dog'
do'g
```

I worote `^.*'.*`

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex, you can simply:

```
return your_string.count("'") == 1
```

Or if you insist to have `re` imported in your module:

```
import re
return len(re.findall("'", my_string)) == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^[^']*'[^']*$', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "'dog\ndog'\ndo'g"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

It does work .See here.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/52

You can also try

```
^(?=[^']*'[^']*$).*$
```

This use lookahead to find `'`.

Comment: This finds string with multiple apostrophes as well. You'll have to specify "not apostrophes" like `^[^']*'[^']*$`.

Comment: @omertalmi can you state which case failed

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with the below regex.

```
^(\w*'{1}\w*)$
```

Matches

```
'dog
dog'
do'g
```

Does not match

```
dog
do''g
''dog
'dog'
dog''
```

Look at the [Regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/vQ3rL2/1).

Answer (score 0):

like that:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"(?<![\w'])(?:\w+'\w*|'\w+)(?![\w'])", "'dog cat dog' m'a'ow do'g")
```

`(?<![\w'])` is a negative lookbehind that checks there is no word characters or quotes before.
`(?![\w'])` is a negative lookahead that checks there is no word characters or quotes after.

So these tests ensure there is only one quote.

[more about lookaround](http://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)